# Using an API to get the location details, based on ZIP code

Tags: android, google-api, location

In my Android app I want to use 'Country' and 'Zip code' to get 'State name' and 'City' or 'Village name'.

Is there any API available to get these information?

Comment: You can use https://www.thezipcodes.com/ as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#Geocoding), simple HTTP request with JSON response.

Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=94085&region=us

```
{
    long_name: "California",
    short_name: "CA",
    types: [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
    ]
}
```

But note that the free tier will support only:

- 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
- 5 requests per second.

Answer (score 33):

For India, You can use below API

```
http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/<your_pin_code>
```

Response :

```
{
  "Message": "Number of Post office(s) found: 2",
  "Status": "Success",
  "PostOffice": [
    {
      "Name": "ISRO Anthariksha Bhavan",
      "Description": "",
      "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
      "DeliveryStatus": "Non-Delivery",
      "Taluk": "Bangalore North",
      "Circle": "Bangalore North",
      "District": "Bangalore",
      "Division": "Bangalore East",
      "Region": "Bangalore HQ",
      "State": "Karnataka",
      "Country": "India"
    },
    {
      "Name": "R.M.V. Extension II Stage",
      "Description": "",
      "BranchType": "Sub Post Office",
      "DeliveryStatus": "Delivery",
      "Taluk": "Bangalore North",
      "Circle": "Bangalore North",
      "District": "Bangalore",
      "Division": "Bangalore East",
      "Region": "Bangalore HQ",
      "State": "Karnataka",
      "Country": "India"
    }
  ]
}
```

for international postal pincode locations use this

```
https://api.worldpostallocations.com/pincode?postalcode=<your_pin_code_eg: 560094>&countrycode=<two_digit_country_code_eg:IN>
```

Response

```
{
  "status": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "305160",
      "country": "IN",
      "postalCode": "560094",
      "postalLocation": "ISRO Anthariksha Bhavan",
      "state": "Karnataka",
      "stateId": "19",
      "district": "Bengaluru",
      "districtId": "583",
      "province": "Bangalore North",
      "provinceId": "",
      "latitude": "13.1077",
      "longitude": "77.581"
    },
    {
      "id": "305159",
      "country": "IN",
      "postalCode": "560094",
      "postalLocation": "R.M.V. Extension II Stage",
      "state": "Karnataka",
      "stateId": "19",
      "district": "Bengaluru",
      "districtId": "583",
      "province": "Bangalore North",
      "provinceId": "",
      "latitude": "13.1077",
      "longitude": "77.581"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was using http://postalpincode.in/api/pincode/<your_pin_code> api, but it was giving Network Error. So, I checked the docs and got know that api has changed i.e. https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/<your_pin_code>

Comment: Seems like it is not reliable. I am getting array of objects instead of single object. Data is completly random. Some object has correct details. Some are having wrong name/district/ etc

Answer (score 1):

May Help

https://www.whizapi.com/open-api/api-details?id=20

URL-> https://www.WhizAPI.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-city-by-postal-code?AppKey=your-app-key&pin=110001

RESPONSE:

```
{
"ResponseCode": 0,
"ResponseMessage": "OK",
"ResponseDateTime": "11/10/2014 8:17:20 AM GMT",
"Data": [
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Baroda House"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Bengali Market"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Bhagat Singh Market"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Connaught Place"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Constitution House"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Election Commission"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Janpath"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Krishi Bhawan"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Lady Harding Medical College"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "New Delhi",
        "Address": "New Delhi G.P.O."
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "North Avenue"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Parliament House"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Patiala House"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Pragati Maidan Camp"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Pragati Maidan"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Rail Bhawan"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Sansad Marg"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Sansadiya Soudh"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Secretariat North"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Shastri Bhawan"
    },
    {
        "Pincode": "110001",
        "Country": "INDIA",
        "City": "Central Delhi",
        "Address": "Supreme Court"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: have u any api key for testing purpose if yes plz provide me else is this api working wih any pincode ?

Comment: Not able to open site

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Google geocoder you can get the State and City by parsing the returned json or xml and referencing the appropriate fields. For example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=94040
```

returns

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "94040",
               "short_name" : "94040",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            ...
```

Comment: Getting ERROR : You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Comment: Its asking for API key